# USGS Landsat: Use of earth explorer

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, usgs

I am new in the field of geospatial analysis and I'm trying to learn how to process satellites images for remote sensing purposes. I think that my problem is a very basic one.

I'm following some tutorials that suggest to download Landsat CDR from Earth explorer provided by USGS. Unfortunately, despite I am correctly logged in, the option to download what I want do not appear to me (see attached images taken from one previously cited tutorial).

How can I do to resolve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. You might want to select Landsat Archive instead of CDR and select any additional criteria such as percent cloud cover etc. 
Landsat CDR refers to Climate Data Records. See - https://pubs.usgs.gov/fs/2013/3117/pdf/fs2013-3117.pdf ; whereas Landsat archive gives you a host of land cover related products from 1972.

Comment: Many thanks for your kind reply! Just one last question: which is the difference between "Landsat CDR" and "Landsat Archive"?